# PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jboss7.x, cdi

Application starts with path

```
http://localhost:8080/Shop24/catalog.jsf
```

and results in error

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /catalog.xhtml @110,63
>   binding="#{catalog.dataTable}": Target Unreachable, identifier
>   'catalog' resolved to null

a bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Catalog implements Serializable {
```

a configuration

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and server is Jboss7.

What is the reason for that error?

Comment: What does the log say when you deploy your app? is CDI activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating an empty file beans.xml in web-inf folder project starts succesfully.